# Python csv writerow not creating multiple columns

Tags: python, excel, csv

I am simply trying to create csv file from lists. Here's the sample code:

```
import csv

def funcc(data):
    with open("sample.csv", "wb") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f) 
        writer.writerows(data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = [['id', 'name', 'score'], 
            ['1', 'john', '2332'],
            ['2', 'ned', '1213'],
            ['3', 'rob', '8343']]
    funcc(data)
```

This creates the output but everything is in one column. I tried using `csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')` and `csv.writer(f, dialect='excel')`, as mentioned in many SO answers, but nothing seems to work.

The output remains the same:[image: all items in single column]

Is there something I am missing or not doing right??

Comment: CSV means simply "Comma Separated". You could achieve all this very easily without the `csv` module, using Python's "native" file operations.

Comment: yes correct, turned out it was just simple piece of detail about I was missing opening it in 'LibreOfffice'. Format is right everything is right, I could not see the intended output, so I guessed something was wrong.

Comment: If you are using Python 2.x, your file should be opened with `'wb'` not just `'w'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a dialog window with import settings when you open this file in libreoffice. Try to change separator and it should be fine.

Comment: thank you for informing, missed that piece of detail, I can see more clear now! :D